# How to implement GraphQL schema stitching with authentication for microservices in .NET Core 6

Tags: graphql, jwt, microservices, asp.net-core-6.0, hotchocolate

How we can pass auth token to micro services when we use GraphQL schema stitching with authorization for micro services in .NET Core 6 Hotchocolate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HeaderPropagation` NuGet package to forward the `Authorization` header to your services.

```cs
services.AddHeaderPropagation(options =>
{
    options.Headers.Add("Authorization");
});
```

```
app.UseHeaderPropagation();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I just wanted to add that for .NET Core 8, I had to also add a ".AddHeaderPropagation()" to each http client used in the schema stitching: "builder.Services.AddHttpClient(SCHEMA_CONTACTS, c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(graphQlSettings.ContactsServiceUrl)).AddHeaderPropagation();"